# Resource not accessible by integration - Github Action fails for pushed commit, but not for commit via web UI using the same account

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

So, maybe someone here can help me.

I've been trying to figure out why I get a `Unhandled error: HttpError: Resource not accessible by integration` when an action tries to tag a commit with the version number.

The Action's tagging step fails when I edit, commit and push a file from my local machine, but if I do the same via the GitHub UI I get a successful build.

Both are done using the same github account.

The only difference that I can spot is that the commit is ['Verified'](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification) when I do it from the web ui, but not when I push from my local machine.

The action file is below and not rocket science. The failing step uses `actions/github-script`, authenticated using the GITHUB_TOKEN, to create a version tag in the repo on a successfull publish.

The GITHUB_TOKEN  permissions are 'exactly the same' for both a failing and a successfull run. 'exactly the same' is in quotes because the result obviously says different. ( see below for `Set up job` step output)

So my questions are:

- What permission is different?
- What causes the difference?
- How can I tell which permission differ between both scenarios from the action output, because the GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions section from the `Set up job` output either lies or is incomplete?

For now I've 'fixed it' by giving the action [`write-all` permissions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions) using:

```
permissions: write-all
```

I could've also fixed it using a custom API token in a action secret,
but this question is more about understanding the why of it.

## Action Definition

```
name: Publish Packages

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

## some steps omitted for brevity ###

    - name: Tag Release
      uses: actions/github-script@v6.4.1
      with:
        script: |
          const tagName = '${{ steps.gitversion.outputs.majorMinorPatch }}';
          const commitSha = process.env.GITHUB_SHA;
          const { owner, repo } = context.repo;
          console.log(`Creating new tag: ${tagName}...`);
          const tag = await github.rest.git.createRef({
            owner: owner,
            repo: repo,
            ref: `refs/tags/${tagName}`,
            sha: commitSha,
          });
          console.log(`Created new tag: ${tagName}`);
```

## Tag Release step output (when failing)

```
1s
Run actions/github-script@v6.4.1
Creating new tag: 1.1.1...
RequestError [HttpError]: Resource not accessible by integration
    at /home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6.4.1/dist/index.js:6842:21
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async eval (eval at callAsyncFunction (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6.4.1/dist/index.js:15143:16), <anonymous>:10:13)
    at async main (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/github-script/v6.4.1/dist/index.js:15236:20) {
  status: 403,
  response: {
Error: Unhandled error: HttpError: Resource not accessible by integration
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/[REDACTED]/git/refs',
    status: 403,
    headers: {
      'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, X-GitHub-SSO, X-GitHub-Request-Id, Deprecation, Sunset',
      connection: 'close',
      'content-encoding': 'gzip',
      'content-security-policy': "default-src 'none'",
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      date: 'Tue, 11 Apr 2023 16:04:59 GMT',
      'referrer-policy': 'origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
      server: 'GitHub.com',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      vary: 'Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-frame-options': 'deny',
      'x-github-api-version-selected': '2022-11-28',
      'x-github-media-type': 'github.v3; format=json',
      'x-github-request-id': '[REDACTED]',
      'x-ratelimit-limit': '1000',
      'x-ratelimit-remaining': '998',
      'x-ratelimit-reset': '1681232100',
      'x-ratelimit-resource': 'core',
      'x-ratelimit-used': '2',
      'x-xss-protection': '0'
    },
    data: {
      message: 'Resource not accessible by integration',
      documentation_url: 'https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/git#create-a-reference'
    }
  },
  request: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/[REDACTED]/git/refs',
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
      'user-agent': 'actions/github-script octokit-core.js/3.6.0 Node.js/16.16.0 (linux; x64)',
      authorization: 'token [REDACTED]',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
    },
    body: '{"ref":"refs/tags/1.1.1","sha":"[REDACTED]"}',
    request: { agent: [Agent], hook: [Function: bound bound register] }
  }
}
```

GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions

```
  Actions: write
  Checks: write
  Contents: write
  Deployments: write
  Discussions: write
  Issues: write
  Metadata: read
  Packages: write
  Pages: write
  PullRequests: write
  RepositoryProjects: write
  SecurityEvents: write
  Statuses: write
```

## Tag Release step output (when successfull)

The step output just echos the tagging script.

GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions (exactly the same as the failing step!)

```
GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
  Actions: write
  Checks: write
  Contents: write
  Deployments: write
  Discussions: write
  Issues: write
  Metadata: read
  Packages: write
  Pages: write
  PullRequests: write
  RepositoryProjects: write
  SecurityEvents: write
  Statuses: write
```

## Some links I found during my investigations

- [Permissions for the GITHUB_TOKEN](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token)
- [Security Hardening of Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions)
- [Commit Signature Verification](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification)

Answer (score 19):

In my case, the actions were failing because I had not given them write permissions in the repo.

To do this, go to your repo `settings page` -> `actions`

[image: sidebar where actions tab is]

in the `workflows permissions` change it to `read and write permissions` if it wasn't this.

[image: permissions to change]

Comment: Thanks for providing this, saved me loads of work.  I am learning GitHub administration.  Recently, the GITHUB_TOKEN was changed from allowing everything to least privilege, not sure if that's the reason the radio button defaults to the 2nd option above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going into the github settings web console, you can specify the permissions directly in your github action YML. Here is your YAML from above, but with my added "permissions: contents: write":

```
name: Publish Packages

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]

# Permission can be added at job level or workflow level
permissions:
  contents: write   # This is required to create/push the new git tag

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - ... all your other steps...

    - name: Tag Release
      uses: actions/github-script@v6.4.1
      with:
        script: |
          const tagName = '${{ steps.gitversion.outputs.majorMinorPatch }}';
          const commitSha = process.env.GITHUB_SHA;
          const { owner, repo } = context.repo;
          console.log(`Creating new tag: ${tagName}...`);
          const tag = await github.rest.git.createRef({
            owner: owner,
            repo: repo,
            ref: `refs/tags/${tagName}`,
            sha: commitSha,
          });
          console.log(`Created new tag: ${tagName}`);
```